# how can inserting arrays into different rows in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

When i Focusout on AGE module only first row array inserted,how can i multiple array insert?

HTML Form:

```
$j=2;
for($i=0;$i< $j; $i++)
{
    ?>
    First name :: <input name="firstname[]" type="text" id="firstname" value=""/><br>
    Age :: <input name="age[]" type="text" id="age" value="" /><br>
    <?php
}
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $('#age').focusout(function () {
      var fname = $('#firstname').val();
      var ag = $('#age').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'responce_for_jquery_loop.php',
        data: { firstname: fname, age: ag },
        success(result) {
          if (result == 1) {
            alert('Added. Thank you');
          } else {
            alert(result);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: If you are using [] for name attribute in HTML then no need to go for a loop in jQuery. You can use form serialise method in data. In Php you will get an array of firstName, age etc. so $_REQUEST['firstName'] will be array this time not any value. Give it a try.

Comment: thanks,but when i focusout of age module of first array so second array automatically inserted blank value.

Comment: yes because you are keeping same id for different elements. use separate ID for each element. You can not keep one ID for multiple fields wether they are of same type. either use different id or concate $i as prefix or suffix to already existed id.

Comment: Accept my answer if its working fine for you

Comment: Php code Is it ok or not?     for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
  {
   $firstname=$_POST["firstname"][$i];
   $lastname=$_POST["lastname"][$i];
   $age=$_POST["age"][$i];

   $query= "insert into register (firstname,lastname,age) values('$firstname','$lastname','$age')";
   IUDQuery($query); 
  }

Comment: replace 2 with count($_POST['firstname']). then create an array of value to insert into DB. after that outside the loop run query once only to enter multiple record at once.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript remove for loop and both variable containing value for inputs. just use this code to send form data to php page.

```
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'responce_for_jquery_loop.php',
     data:$('#formID").serialize(),
     success:function(result) {...}
    });
```

now in PHP use $_REQUEST['firstName] or $_POST['firstName] and now it will return one array to you containing all input field for having same input name.

Let me know if it doesn't work.